# what will bash do with an unset variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am confused by the behavior about how do bash treat a unset variable used in a shell command, like below:

`rm -rf /$TO_BE_REMOVED`

what will be done if i have not defined a variable `TO_BE_REMOVED`.

Comment: If you're running from root user it will be all fireworks effectively using `rm -rf /`

Comment: I wouldn't do that if I were you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do that, the command executed will effectively try to remove `/` which is very, very bad.  I mean, it will probably mostly fail (unless you're running as root), but still, it will be very bad.

You can avoid many of these sorts of bugs in Bash automatically with one simple command:

```
set -eu
```

If you put that at the top of your Bash script, the interpreter will stop and return an error code if your script ever invokes a command which returns an error which is not checked (that's the `-e` part), or if it uses an undefined variable (the `-u` part).  This makes Bash considerably safer.

Comment: Or if you like the code to be a bit more self-explanatory (at the price of being longer), `set -o errexit -o nounset`.

Comment: so, It seems that bash will ignore the unset variables and just make them erased in the commands?

Comment: @andy: Yeah, sort of like that.

Comment: @John ,does bash offically mention somewhere that bash should behave like this?